# Angular Resource query() does not return expected response

Tags: angularjs

My question is similar to [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196121/angular-access-resource-value-in-controller/16197255#16197255).

I created a service (CoffeeScript)

```
dpmp.factory 'Keyword', ($resource) ->
  $resource '/keywords:id', {}, {query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}}
```

which gets the right http response,

```
{"title":"sysomos","subtitle":"Top keywords by mentions","unit":"times","data":[{"category":"partager","quantity":9753},{"category":"keyword1","quantity":6352},{"category":"keyword2","quantity":6311},{"category":"keyword3","quantity":2983},{"category":"keyword4","quantity":10}]}
```

I want to get data out of the resource in the controller, i.e.

```
$scope.keywords = Keyword.get()
```

But this code does not work. When I do

```
console.log($scope.keywords)
```

I get functions, instead of the data, back. The data is also already there, but I cannot get the data out:

```
> Resource {$get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function, $delete: function}
  > data: Array[5]
    subtitle: "Top keywords by mentions"
    title: "sysomos"
    unit: "times"
  > __proto__: Resource
```

For example, `console.log($scope.keywords.data)` returns `undefined`.

Any solution? Or can you give me an idea what is going on here?

Comment: The question you linked to answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
  Keyword.get(function(data){
 $scope.keywords=data
})
```

Comment: this just works. Although it works, I am not clear why I do not have access to the data object though I already have the data with `$scope.keywords = Keyword.query()`. I can see the data on my Chrome console! In theory, we should be able to do `$scope.keywords = Keyword.query()`, then `$scope.$watch "keywords" -> doSomething()`, right?

Comment: since resource is asyncronous so immediately if you do console.log you will get undefined