# Angularjs $resource response is not returning data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying this with $resource I have a service Post

```
app.factory('Post', function ($resource, $cookieStore) {
return $resource('http://localhost:port/posts/:id', {"id":"@id", port:':9000'}, {
    query: { method:'GET', isArray: true , headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+$cookieStore.get("authToken")}},
    save: { method:'POST',headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+$cookieStore.get("authToken")}},
    update: {method:'PUT' ,headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+$cookieStore.get("authToken")}},
    delete : {method: 'DELETE',headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+$cookieStore.get("authToken")}},
    get : { method: 'GET', headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+$cookieStore.get("authToken")}}
});
```

});

And the in the controller I am trying to get all the posts.

```
Post.query(function(data){
    console.log(data.length);
    console.log(data)
});
```

I was expecting the data to be whats returned from the server but the console.log is showing me this how can I get the access to the actual json data from server?

```
3 posts.js:18
[Resource, Resource, Resource, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
0: Resource
1: Resource
2: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: I looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196121/angular-access-resource-value-in-controller/ but the same thing is not working

Comment: Are you sure that your server returns data? Try with fiddler your query first.

Comment: Yes it is . I can see the data in the Resource object for index 0, 1 and 2. The data is basically the array with 3 Resource object which has the data recieved from the server but along with that it has a $promise object and $resolved in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) it seems that first parameter in action is parameter object for query and only then success callback. So try:

```
Post.query({}, function(data) {
    console.log(data.length);
    console.log(data);
})
```

You also can use $promise:

```
Post.query({}).$promise.then((function(data) {
    console.log(data.length);
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Yes I missed the parameter object.